Can not run Spark server and connect to it
I am trying to run Spark through Spark connect on local machine.
The OS I am using is Ubunut using Spark 3.5.1 on JDK 17
Running Spark server through below command:
./start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.13:3.5.1,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0

It gives error in the logs as below
24/06/18 06:53:47 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.service.SparkConnectServer$.main(SparkConnectServer.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.service.SparkConnectServer.main(SparkConnectServer.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
24/06/18 06:53:47 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
24/06/18 06:53:47 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2888)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:1099)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:1093)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.service.SparkConnectServer$.main(SparkConnectServer.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.service.SparkConnectServer.main(SparkConnectServer.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
24/06/18 06:53:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/06/18 06:53:47 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a3c256ab-e2fc-4974-abac-e3d730cbbe6a

I try to provide the --master and running using below
./start-connect-server.sh --master local[* ]--packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0

I got below error:
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17-oracle-x64/bin/java -cp /home/mahdi/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/conf/:/home/mahdi/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3/jars/* -Xmx1g -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Djdk.reflect.useDirectMethodHandle=false org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master local[* --class org.apache.spark.sql.connect.service.SparkConnectServer --name Spark Connect server spark-internal ]--packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0
========================================
24/06/18 21:42:47 WARN Utils: Your hostname, mahdi-VirtualBox resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
24/06/18 21:42:47 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Remote cannot be specified with master and/or deploy mode.
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:650)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateSubmitArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.validateArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1103)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1103)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

